# Returning keys nested dictionary with Python

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

EDIT: Thanks to @arzo for the catch

I have a nested dictionary structured as:

```
{
"key1":"string",
"key2":[{"nestedkey":"nestedvalue"}],
"key3":[1,2,3],
"key4":[{"nestedlevel1key":[{"nestedlevel2key":"nestedlevel2value"}]}],
"key5": {},
"key6": {"regularkey": "regularvalue"},
"key7": 15
}
```

In which a dictionary key can contain:

1. strings
2. ints
3. lists of dictionaries
4. lists of dictionaries that contain lists of dictionaries
5. an empty dictionary
6. a regular dictionary

The problem statement is optimizing a method that can handle returning all of the keys within a dictionary. I can write something like this:

```
def get_keys(dict_example):
    keys = []

    for k,v in dict_example.items():
        keys.append(k)
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            for k in v.keys():
                keys.append(k)
        if isinstance(v, list):
            if isinstance(v[0], dict):
                for k,v in v[0].items():
                    keys.append(k)
                    if isinstance(v, list) and isinstance(v[0], dict):
                        for k in v[0].keys():
                            keys.append(k) 
    return keys
         keys = get_keys(dict_example)

            
print(keys)
```

Which will get me (in no particular order) a list of the keys:

```
['key1', 'key2', 'nestedkey1', 'key3', 'key4', 'nestedlevel1key', 'nestedlevel2key', 'key5', 'key6', 'regularkey', 'key7']
```

But I am not sure of an optimized method that is simplified to take on all the 6 use cases that can also transverse through the array, regardless of how many levels there are. Now I made the heuristic of the number of levels, but there could be deeper levels within this array that I need to account for.

Comment: isn't regularkey missing ?

Comment: @arzo Oh, thank you for that. It is missing actually! That should be included in this, which needs another condition added to the current logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are only 2 cases to handle : `list` and `dict` as they contain other thing, then use recursivity

- for a `dict` : keeps keys, and search throught values
- for `list` : search throught values

```
def get_keys(item):
    keys = []
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        for k, v in item.items():
            keys.append(k)
            keys.extend(get_keys(v))
    elif isinstance(item, (list, tuple)):
        for x in item:
            keys.extend(get_keys(x))
    return keys
```

---

```
values = {
    "key1": "string", "key2": [{"nestedkey": "nestedvalue"}], "key3": [1, 2, 3],
    "key4": [{"nestedlevel1key": [{"nestedlevel2key": "nestedlevel2value"}]}],
    "key5": {}, "key6": {"regularkey": "regularvalue"},
}

keys = get_keys(values)
print(keys)
# ['key1', 'key2', 'nestedkey', 'key3', 'key4', 'nestedlevel1key', 'nestedlevel2key', 'key5', 'key6', 'regularkey']
```

Comment: Thank you @argo! Is this method also optimal for finding out at what level each key is? For instance, "nestedlevel1key" is at level 1, "nestedlevel2key" is at level 2, and so on

Answer (score 2):

Rather than a high number of nested loops, you can solve this with a recursive function:

```py
origDict = {
"key1":"string",
"key2":[{"nestedkey":"nestedvalue"}],
"key3":[1,2,3],
"key4":[{"nestedlevel1key":[{"nestedlevel2key":"nestedlevel2value"}]}],
"key5": {},
"key6": {"regularkey": "regularvalue"},
"key7": 15
}

keyList = []

def get_keys(inDict, listOfKeys):
    for k, v in inDict.items():
        listOfKeys.append(k)
        if isinstance(v, list):
            for item in v:
                if isinstance(item, dict):
                    get_keys(item, listOfKeys)
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            get_keys(v, listOfKeys)

get_keys(origDict, keyList)
print(keyList)
```

This prints:

````
['key1', 'key2', 'nestedkey', 'key3', 'key4', 'nestedlevel1key', 
'nestedlevel2key', 'key5', 'key6', 'regularkey', 'key7']```
````